# Android VideoView not playing video

Tags: java, android, android-videoview

I have a problem with my VideoView.
Just tried to make a simple example:

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

String url = "http://videoguides.avs4you.com/How-to-convert-3GP-video.aspx";
VideoView video;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    video = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.videoView);

    video.setVideoPath(url);
    video.start();
    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),url,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

}
```

}

But i get this errors:

[image]

Sometimes i just get the sound but black videoscreen.
Plus i dont get any errors in my LogCat!

Answer (score 1):

A video view in android does not support any `.aspx` videos. You should use `.mp4`, `.3gb`, `.mkv` or `.webm` instead.

Have a closer look here at the video-section : http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/media-formats.html#core

Here is an example for a video you can use instad (for testing) : http://clips.vorwaerts-gmbh.de/VfE_html5.mp4

I Hope this really helps you

Comment: Hi!
I tried to replace my URL to ="http://clips.vorwaerts-gmbh.de/VfE_html5.mp4" but its still dosent work with the same code as above :(

Comment: Sorry!
Forgot to relauch emulator!
It works!
Thank you!

Comment: Can i ask you one more question?
When i record a video in the emulator where is the video stored by default?
In the sdcard folder?

Comment: sorry, I didn't work on anything like that, but I looked up a bit, so look up here: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/camera.html#capture-video and here:http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/camera.html#saving-media

Answer (score 0):

Your url returned html code, and VideoView needed streaming resource (full path to the video).

And if you want showing youtube video you need to usage  [youtube API](https://www.youtube.com/yt/dev/ru/api-resources.html)

See also https://developers.google.com/youtube/android/player/